# Gnome Online Accounts through proxy

Tags: proxy, online-accounts

I am trying to set up my Google Account through Online Accounts, but all I get is the blank screen.

[image]

I am behind an authenticated proxy server.

I have set up the following

- Proxy environment variables.
- Proxy settings in the Network Settings Dialog.
- Proxy settings in both GConf and Dconf.

Despite all this, I am not able to connect to my account.

This has been [reported in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1048590), and as per the bug report, the problem has been solved, but I am still facing problem.

Any help in this regard, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem :(

Comment: Have you installed the [right version 0.0.18-0ubuntu1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/0.0.18-0ubuntu1), not …1.1?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for very long time.Here's how I solved it:

(Follow the steps serially)

#### **1. For gtk3 programs such as rhythmbox and online accounts:**

First you need to enter proxy settings in network settings (along with authentication):

[image]

Then apply system wide.

#### **2. For apt,software center etc**

edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

And then replace all the existing text by the following lines

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@host:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@host:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@host:port/";
```

#### **3. Environment variables**

edit the file `/etc/environment`

And then add the following lines after PATH="something here"

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@host:port/
https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

That's all..