# How to add online accounts behind transparent Squid proxy?

Tags: proxy, online-accounts, squid, oauth

I am behind a transparent proxy (squid) and whenever I try to add an account e.g: facebook, google, etc., this is what appears. This does not happen when I connect to the net directly.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

[image: Blank Page]

Comment: same question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/181371/google-keep-asking-for-permission-to-authorize-my-online-account and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/205051/how-to-configure-proxy-for-online-account-authentication?rq=1 and this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/227441/gnome-online-accounts-through-proxy?rq=1

Comment: Confirmed duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/205051/how-to-configure-proxy-for-online-account-authentication?rq=1.

Comment: The thing is, with transparent proxies, the user doesn't have to set proxy settings. That's the whole point of transparent proxies.

Comment: This looks like a likely duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/205051/how-to-configure-proxy-for-online-account-authentication). Can you please confirm whether or not that helps you any Rey?

Comment: Seth, I have tried that solution already but sadly, to no avail.

Comment: I was wondering if it had something to do with HTTP->HTTPS connections, because a while back I could manually route my port 443 to 80 through iptables and it worked for online accounts, but squid refused to load on my browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> All parts of this answer have been re-worded from [Fossfreedom's Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/186562/208574) available here. You should read it, as it gives picture examples and gives a solely command-line method as well.

Instead of running a proxy by using the GUI settings menu, you can use DConf.

First off, install `dconf-tools` and run `dconf-editor` in a console. It should open a GUI.

Under `org.gnome.system.proxy`, set the proxy mode to `manual`. Check `use-same-proxy`.

In `http` and `https`, set your according proxy settings.

Relog/reboot and it should be solved.

Comment: Exactly as what muru said above; I'm running a transparent proxy and therefore do not need to set manual proxies. I have tried this solution as well, without any results.

Answer (score 0):

Transparent proxies are for unsecured (e.g. HTTP) connections only.

Adding accounts is done with HTTPS.

HTTPS proxying can only be done explicitly, not transparently. Or, with great effort, you can set up a near-"transparent" HTTPS proxy by emulating a man-in-the-middle attack. (Search the web for "SSL Bump")

You'll need to either set up an SSL bumping proxy, or manually specify the HTTPS (not necessarily HTTP) proxy as described in the other answers relating to non-transparent proxies.

Comment: I do have ssl-bump option set in squid, compiled with --enable-ssl and --enable-ssl-crtd flag. I can't determine if the problem is from squid or online accounts.