# Set proxy for Gnome Online Accounts(Google)

Tags: 18.04, proxy

I understand that [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227441/gnome-online-accounts-through-proxy) can set a global proxy, but how can I set proxy for online-accounts only?

Specifically, I want to enable proxy for syncing the online accounts, while disable the proxy for daily usage.

Comment: I need the opposite: to enable proxy for daily use and disable proxy for google drive in gnome online accounts.